# Image Size Vary in different Android Phone

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

Hello I am downloading the bitmap from URL in Android and setting it to the `imageview`. What weird issue is that same bitmap looks good and large in one Micromax Android phone and in Sony it's size is looking very small.

[image]

See barcode appear very small even I have set it width to `fill_parent`

[image]

and In one phone it appears look good, here both phone have same screen width.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayoutofflipicon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qrCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barCodevaluetextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Scaling in android is resolution based. You can either create bitmaps of different resolutions and put  them in their respective drawable folder, or you you can manually handle your scaling.

Comment: @zgc7009 I am downloading the bitmap from URL so can not put them in respective drawable folder, can you suggest how I can handle this scaling manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by taking large size drawables fixed my issue and   I have also used `scaletype` to centerInside.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ImageView`, change `android:layout_width` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

Comment: No change, it is still same

Comment: @Mick Actually, try removing `android:scaleType` and putting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` back in, that seems to work for me. The key was just the setting the width to match parent.